# How can I change my CSS according to the screen width of a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to to apply a different CSS style to my websites as soon as the width of the document is lower than `700px` and again when it's lower than `500px` (smartphone). The code I have is the following, what did I do wrong?

```
if($(document).width() < 749) {
    if($(document).width() < 700) {
        $('#cirkelcontainer').hide();   
        $('h3').css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
        $('.datum').css('width', '100%');
        $('.datum').css('color', 'black');
        $('.datum').css('margin-top', '13px');
        $('.datum').css('background-color', 'white');
        $('.datum').css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
        $('.datum').css('height', 'auto');
        $('.datum').css('margin-left', '-2%');
        $('#nieuwsnavlinks').css('width', '90%');
        $('#nieuwsnavlinks p').css('text-align', 'center');
        $('#nieuwsnavrechts').css('width', '228px');
        $('#nieuwsnavrechts').css('margin-left', 'auto');
        $('#nieuwsnavrechts').css('margin-right', 'auto');
        $('#nieuwsnavrechts').css('float', 'none');
        $('content').css('padding-bottom', '25px');
    }

    if($(document).width() < 500) {
        $('button').css('width', '100%');
        $('form button').css('width', '125px'); 
        $('#datum:nth-child(n)').hide();
        $('#nieuwsoverzicht:nth-child(n)').css({
            'width': '100%',
            'height': 'auto',
            'float': 'left'
        });
        $('nav ul ul li').css('border-left', '1px dotted black');
        $('#nieuwsoverzicht:nth-child(n) p').css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
        $('h4').css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
        $('content').css('width', '100%');
        $('.nieuwstext:nth-child(1)').find('a').html('&#x25C0;');
        $('.nieuwstext:last').find('a').html('&#x25B6;');
        $('#nieuwsnavrechts').css('width', '162px');
    }
}
```

EDIT: It works perfect in a normal browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a standard feature of CSS allowing just this : having sets of rules which apply for certain conditions, for example window size.

This feature is called media queries. Here's [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

You would have for example

```
/* here the rules for small windows */
@media (max-width: 500px) { 
    #cirkelcontainer {
         display: none;
    }
    h3 {
         word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}

/* here the rules for windows between 500px and 900px */
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    form button {
         width: 125px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:**

Use [Media Queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries) instead.

**What is it?**

> Media Queries is a CSS3 module allowing content rendering to adapt to
>   conditions such as screen resolution (e.g. smartphone vs. high
>   definition screen). It became a W3C recommended standard in June 2012
>   and is a cornerstone technology of Responsive Web Design.

**How to use it?**

You can find a guide [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and some real world examples [here](http://mediaqueri.es/).

**Example:**

```
// Inside HTML header:
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/default.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/mobile.css' />
```

The advantage of splitting CSS in two different files make easier to maintain and `mobile.css` won't be imported if your user is on a desktop.

```
// Inside CSS file (default.css):
@media screen and (min-width:500px) { ... }
```

The advantage of specifying all CSS styles for all resolutions in one file (default.css) is that if you are on a desktop and resize your browser window your website will automatically adapt. To improve maintenance you may want to split to a file per device type but import all the files in all pages.

**Note:**

There are many ways to implement this, like mobile-first or desktop-first. As per your question in all cases you don't need to change your HTML, but only specify resolution criteria for each group of style (in a separated CSS file or not).

You can look at my examples above, but if you are interested by real example you can find a lot on the Web. I let you resize your browser window on the [Microsoft home page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/default.aspx) and look at how elements change (menu, carousel, columns, ...).

**Going further:**

There are lots of frameworks on the Web that help you to do great things. I particularly like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) ([Grid example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)) but there are other alternatives.

Comment: Ok, thanks but I dont quite get it: do I have to add both the html meta tag or only the css queries. And also: do i wrap my plain css than between such queries or not?

Comment: @user2583429: I have updated my answer. Media Queries are part of CSS3, which means you just have to import your stylesheet (in `head` tag) and your browser will take care to use the correct styles. I would suggest to create a specific CSS file per resolution type (eg default.css, desktop.css, tablet.css, smartphone.css...), but keep in mind that for each type there are lots of possible resolution. In this case you can add small style changes in "desktp.css" for example and/or use frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Try this on a page and resize your browser window.